# WiFi connection is unstable when uploading (or perhaps downloading) large files with FTP

Tags: wi-fi, internet, ftp

I use an app like WiFi FTP Server or Files on Xiaomi Poco 3. Everything works perfectly. However, often the upload break. I notice that I cannot access the internet either when that happens.

Quickly turning on and off WiFi fixes the issue and if fast enough, the file transfer will resume.

I use an app for pinging.

[image].[image]

As you see, after a while, pinging the router IP will fail.

However, turning off and turning on WiFi quickly will restore connections. This is of course a very annoying problem. That's because I have to keep guarding the smartphone.

As far as I know, this is only happening when uploading large files. If I do nothing, the WiFi is fine. I am using WiFi FTP Server app on Android and FileZilla on my computer. I don't think the problem is in either software. Using Xiaomi's own Files will have the same problem.

[image]

How to fix this? What can possibly go wrong?

Comment: Wifi is a shared media, collisions can occur at any time that is nothing unusual. What Wifi channel(s) does you Wifi use? If your Wifi supports "extra wide/broad channels" disable them. The wider a channel is the higher the chance for disturbances. If router and phone support it make sure to use 5GHz Wifi usually this frequency range is not so crowded.

Comment: Is the ping stable on the PC? There's a possibility that the router/ISP may do some throttling/back off when it detects a surge of bandwidth usage.

Comment: Let me check. Router throttling back when it detects a surge of bandwidth use? Interesting. How do I find out?